# I want use GuzzleHttp with Socks5 proxy

Tags: php, linux, windows, proxy, guzzle

#### What i want to do

I want use `GuzzleHttp` with `Socks5 proxy`.

#### The problem

It's not working on Linux.
It's successfully workin on Windows.
(Same progam to Linux)

```
$ php index.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: Connection refused for URI https://api.ipify.org in /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php:311
Stack trace:
#0 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(230): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}()
#1 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(322): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createResource(Object(Closure))
#2 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(58): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createStream(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#3 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(35): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#4 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#5 /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::Gu in /root/test/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 72
```

#### Program

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

**composer.json**

```json
{
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2"
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://api.ipify.org';

$response = $client->get($url, [
'proxy' => "socks5://10.0.0.2:8080",
'timeout' => 60, // 60 second
'verify' => false
]);

var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

#### What i try 1

```
'proxy' => "socks5h://10.0.0.2:8080"
```

No effect to result.
Ref: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1484#issuecomment-306724234

#### What i try 2

```
'proxy' => "tcp://10.0.0.2:8080"
```

No effect to result.
Ref: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1484#issue-157978804

#### Tested Environment(Proxy Server)

https://pypi.org/project/pproxy/

```
$ pproxy -l socks5://0.0.0.0:8080
```

#### Tested Environment(PHP)

- `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` + `php 7.3.24-3` Not working
- `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS(WSL)` + `php 7.4.3`Not woring
- `Windows 10 1903 64bit` + `php 7.2.12` Successfully working

Comment: have you configured socks5 server in ubuntu using Dante or something else

Comment: I'm install Dante `apt install dante-server`, and test it.
But it's not workin on Linux. Windows can connect to Dante server as same as `pproxy`.
Install log https://pastebin.com/8CxT83h9

Comment: It will not help if you just say not working, also you can post your question on dante not working on https://askubuntu.com/, users with better experience on ubuntu can help you there, If dante or any other socks5 server can't work then guzzle is just a connector, guzzle can't help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to solve

Just install `php-curl`

```
apt install php7.3-curl
```

## Before

```
$ php -i | grep cURL
(No output)
```

## After

```
$ php -i | grep cURL
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.68.0
```

## Run program on Linux

Successfully working

```
$ php index.php 
string(15) "xxx.xxx.xxx.x"
```

Comment: Without cURL installed you Guzzle was using stream handler instead of curl handler under the hood. I wonder if you ever had to use stream handler + proxy intentionally? I'm asking because I'm struggling with it right now and it's giving me the same connection refused error